# Applications created with real basic (real studio) for mac or windows

Tags: macos, programming-languages, realbasic

i have search high and low on the internet and it does not exist. i cant find a single website that shows a few applications created with realbasic. i saw a video that shows the user going to realbasic.com/community/ and it shows a load of applications created using realbasic. would anyone know where i can find this information. that link that i gave doesnt even work by them.

Comment: Are you looking for tutorials on how to do it, or just the names of some Applications created with REALbasic?

Answer (score 2):

The Made with REALbasic section at the Association of REALbasic Developers contains a list of many applications created with REALbasic:

http://www.arbpmembers.org/index.php?option=com_resource&view=list&category_id=10&Itemid=49

(Disclaimer: I am a board member of ARBP)

My site, RBDevZone, also has a community section:

http://www.rbdevzone.com/community/

Answer (score 2):

There is also a fairly lengthy thread on the REALbasic Forums.  Direct link:  http://forums.realsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=25866